# Invoke Lambda function on CodePipeline Stage or Action Failure

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

When CodePipeline creates production assets we're required to file a Request For Change.

Opening the RFC when entering the Production Stage and closing the RFC on a successful Production build/test is easy enough by firing Lambdas. The question comes when a CodePipeline Stage or Test Action fails.

How to fire Lambda when a CodePipeline Stage fails?
Similarly how to fire a Lambda when a CodePipeline Test Action fails?

[Example cloudformation](https://github.com/byu-oit-appdev/iac/tree/master/cloudformation/codepipeline)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From AWS:

The ability to get notified with the relevant details when a pipeline fails to complete is a popular feature request (asked by multiple customers and very valid use-case to have) and I can confirm that it is on the service team roadmap but they haven't provided an ETA on this request (I would recommend checking the release history page for this service : link https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/AWS-CodePipeline )

As an alternative, other ways to implement this functionality using Lambda are listed below:

1) Have a Lambda function which polls the pipeline state using time based CloudWatch events and triggers an SNS notification when it sees a failed action.

2) Put a Lambda function using our Lambda integration as a parallel action to the action you want to monitor then monitor the status of the other action from within the Lambda function to see if it fails or succeeds. Use continuation tokens to ensure the Lambda function keeps getting invoked until it sees a result in the other action, and send an SNS notification accordingly.

Comment: Do you have an example of a Lambda function for idea number 2)?

Comment: Here's the example of using #2 from @Eric Nord's answer above http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html#actions-invoke-lambda-function-samples

Answer (score 3):

As of July 12, 2017, Amazon has announced the availability of this feature.

Announcement: [Amazon CloudWatch Events now supports AWS CodePipeline as a target](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/amazon-cloudwatch-events-now-supports-aws-codepipeline-as-a-target/)

In the Cloudwatch console, you can already see it as a target.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AWS doesn't provide that feature yet.

Here is the example of a Lambda function that sends Slack notifications when a CodePipeline action is in progress, succeeds or fails: https://github.com/sandtable/codepipelinetoslack

It monitors the status of a parallel CodePipeline action using a continuation token.

Answer (score 1):

I created a project on [GitHub](https://github.com/josep11/lambda-codepipeline-notifications) that allows you to hook a lambda functions to AWS Codepipeline Notifications and gives a nice summary as the output (on an SNS Topic).